# Probability of three independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, random

Assume we have three independent random variables A, B and C. The distribution for A,B and C are known(In this case just assume they are all beta distribution with different parameters). I want to compare the three random variables.

Is this equation ${\rm Pr}(C > A\ and\ C > B) = {\rm Pr}(C > A){\rm Pr}(C > B)$ true or false?I don't know if $C>A$ and $C>B$ are independent of each other or not. Please let me know how to judge that.

Also, ${\rm Pr}(C > A\ or\ C > B) = {\rm Pr}(C > A) + {\rm Pr}(C > B) - {\rm Pr}(C > A\ and\ C > B)$should always be correct since $C>A$ and $C>B$ are not mutually exclusive. Please let me know if I'm right.

Comment: In general, the information that "$C>A$" is evidence to suggest that $C$ is large...hence evidence to suggest $C>B$ as well.  So, no...those events are not independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, $C > A$ and $C > B$ are generally not independent, and so $$Pr(C > A \ \text{and}\ C > B) \ne Pr(C > A) Pr(C > B)$$  Examples are easy (e.g. suppose $A$ and $B$ are almost surely constant).

As for your second question,  $Pr(E \ \text{or}\ F) = Pr(E) + Pr(F) - Pr(E \ \text{and}\ F)$ is always true, and does not depend on  $E$ and $F$ not being mutually exclusive.  Of course if they do happen to be mutually exclusive, $Pr(E \ \text{and}\ F) = 0$.

Comment: Very clear explanation, thank you!